# php returns source code instead of json string

Tags: php, httprequest

My php files are working fine in the browser.

```
$array = array("message" => "Not found", "status_code" => 404);
echo json_encode($array);
```

this works

```
echo file_get_contents("http://localhost/file.php");
```

But it returns source code when I use only file name

```
echo file_get_contents("file.php");
```

response

```
"Not found", "status_code" => 404); echo json_encode($array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This `echo file_get_contents("http://localhost/file.php");` makes a request to the webserver for the file, through localhost, and hence the PHP is processed and executed.

This `echo file_get_contents("file.php");` gets the file directly without going through the webserver, and hence the code in it is not executed, and merely treated as a text file.

If you want to execute the code directly in the current scope, you need to use `include` or `require`:

```
include('file.php');
```

If you want to execute the `file.php` separately (if you need to do this, you are probably doing something wrong), then you can use [`passthru()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php).